# How can I make active selection of a specific part of text in value?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am copying a text value of an object to the textarea. I have placed some other text before and behind the text I am copying. The problem is that I have no idea what to do if I need to make the text in between to be selected (I mean highlighted as an active part of text) this is my code and sorry for my english:

```
            <form id="form" method="POST">

                    <div id="bold" value="BOLD"></div>
                    <textarea class="text_article" name="content" placeholder="Article text"></textarea><br/> 
            <script>
                    $("#form").on("click", "div", function() {
                    var content = $(this).attr("value");

                    $(".text_article").val($(".text_article").val() + "<b>" );
                    $(".text_article").val($(".text_article").val() + content ); 
                    $(".text_article").val($(".text_article").val() + "</b>" );
                });  
            </script>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the form with : `$(this).attr("value")` ?!

Comment: Please show an example

Comment: My code  gets the value of <div id="bold"> than after click it sends the content of the value into a textarea with the <b> before the value content and with </b> behind. It works up here. Then I need to select (highlight but the way you could erase it) the content of the value but just the value not the <b> and </b> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0tzhm2g/1/) if you want to select just the content of the variable `content` without the strings that you are appending, you can do something like this:

```
$(".style_text").on("click", "div", function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("value");
    var startSelectionIndex = $(".text_article").val().length + 3;
    $(".text_article").val($(".text_article").val() +"<b>" + content + "</b>");
    $(".text_article")[0].setSelectionRange(startSelectionIndex, content.length + startSelectionIndex);
    $(".text_article")[0].focus();
});
```

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/z4s2vu6x/).

Comment: Actually It has one mistake that makes problem: If you have already wrote something in the textarea before you add the element value in it. It selects the text from the first 3 characters. I'd like it to highlight the element value every time...Look here https://jsfiddle.net/z0tzhm2g/3/

Comment: You're my hero! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/thqbfjs7/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
<br/>
<span class="style_text">
    <div id="bold" value="BOLD TEXT">CLICK</div>
    <textarea class="text_article" name="content"></textarea><br/> 
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".style_text").on("click", "div", function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("value");
    $(".text_article").val($(".text_article").val() + content).select(); 
    $("textarea").addClass("bold");
});
```

Comment: This is what my code does: https://jsfiddle.net/z0tzhm2g/1/
What I need to do is that just the middle part of the text "BOLD TEXT" to be highlited instead of selecting the whole text

Comment: what exact string you want to be in your textarea?

Comment: exact the one that I already have in it but I want just the text "BOLD TEXT" between tags <b></b> to be selected not the whole text as it is in the example, I have uploaded

Comment: Sorry but that still isn't what I am looking for. I need what I have in my example the whole string even with the tags but I don't want the tags to be highlighted just the text inside them... Is that possible?

Comment: @PetrRajchert Thats not possible. Its because the content inside the textbox is string, not html. You can apply css to the content as a whole, not specific part of the content which is pure string.